# Why is authorized_keys ignored?

Tags: git, ssh, centos

I have a fresh install of CentOS 6.5, which I'm using as a dev server for a small team. We are having a central bare Git repository which we'll be connecting to via ssh.

I have setup a user called `git` and a user called `test`. `test`'s public key has been appended to `git`'s `authorized_keys` file. As far as I can tell the permissions are all correct:

```
[test@hackdashit ~]$ ls -aZ ~/.ssh/
drwx------. test developers unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 .
drwx-----x. test developers unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 ..
-rw-------. test developers unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 authorized_keys
-rw-------. test developers unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 config
-rw-------. test developers unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 id_rsa
-rw-------. test developers unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 id_rsa.pub
```

And the ssh directory itself:

```
[test@hackdashit ~]$ ls -aZ ~
drwx------. test developers unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 .ssh
```

When connecting from a remote machine, using the private key, it connects without the password fine. However when I try to connect locally, I see this:

```
[test@hackdashit ~]$ ssh -v hackdashit
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/test/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for hackdashit
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/test/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

**Note:** I changed the RSA key fingerprint above

These are the contents of my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host hackdashit
  Hostname localhost
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The same thing happens when I try to run Git:

```
[test@hackdashit ~]$ git clone ssh://hackdashit/repos/test.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/test/test/.git/
The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is c3:9f:65:f0:04:39:93:82:7e:1d:57:9b:16:2f:76:59.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here, to get ssh connecting without passwords from the `test` account to the `git` account so I can use Git either locally or remotely via ssh?

**Note:** I've also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377009/adding-public-key-to-ssh-authorized-keys-does-not-log-me-in-automatically) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051846/having-trouble-with-ssh-and-authorized-keys) question on the matter, but I don't think they pertain to me as permissions (including SELinux) appear correct.

**Update**

I stopped `sshd` then ran `sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d` and tried to connect with `ssh test@localhost` with the `~/.ssh/config` file removed, and got the following output:

```
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from ::1 port 39980
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
```

Comment: You should do a `ssh hackdashit` while `sshd -d` is running (and keep the `~/.ssh/config` file). Your test only revealed that the daemon is never contacted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more information, you can try:

```
ssh -Tvvv hackdashit
```

Also:

```
sudo sshd stop
sudo ssh -Dd
```

That way, you will see from the ssh daemon (sshd) point of view what it receives and what it misses to complete the query (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7443893/6309)).

you can also check if you go further with:

```
 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no hackdashit
```

Note that the url to use for git would be:

```
git clone hackdashit:/repos/test.git
```

---

The [OP LeonardChallis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/601299/leonardchallis) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054740/why-is-authorized-keys-ignored/23054951#comment35234642_23054951):

> The `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` sent my down the right route.
>   I ran

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa localhost > /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

> and it magically works :)

Comment: Thank you. The StrictHostKeyChecking=no sent my down the right route. I ran `ssh-keyscan -t rsa localhost > /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` and it magically works :)

Comment: @LeonardChallis Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.